# How do we 'initiate' mail exchange with PGP

Tags: email, pgp

I am totally new with PGP, and I would like to know how I can initiate a mail exchange with it.

I created my public/private keys, and posted my private key on the [MIT PGP Public Key Server](https://pgp.mit.edu/). I can find it on the site now.

What's next? How do I create the encrypted message? (without the need of any software. I just want to understand)

I'm thinking about:

```
# I write my message
$ vim message
$ cat message
Hello, can you read this?

# Add the fingerprint of my public key so the recipient will be able to find the public key on pgp.mit.edu.
$ gpg --fingerprint my-mail-address >> message

# Create the message (I imported the recipient's public key)
$ cat message | gpg --encrypt --armor -r recipient@mail.address
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

[Base64]
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Is this right?

Comment: You added your `private key` to the key server? I assume you mean public.

Comment: `without the need of any software` you mean aside from gpg (and cat and vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from useless use of cat (`<message gpg --encrypt [...]` or `gpg --encrypt [...] message` would do, too) I don't see a real problem here. Adding your fingerprint is sufficient; as an alternative you could also `--sign` the document (the signature also includes it).

The only thing you shouldn't do is referencing your own key using your user ID, provide your [(long) key ID](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/84280/19837) or fingerprint here. Somebody else could create another key with the same user ID, and send you some kind of "drive-by-download" message signed with the fake key, which would result in you possibly downloading it without knowledge.